# Data Attribute Not Persisting on Dynamic DOM

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am creating dynamic DOM elements based on an AJAX request that returns rows from a MySQL database. What I am trying to do is create a font-awesome icon so that it can launch a twitter-bootstrap v.4 modal while using jQuery v.3.2.1. Since the element that launches the modal requires a data-target and data-toggle attribute, I need to also set those values whenever I'm creating the DOM, but for whatever reason, whenever I try the following code it does not work:

```
// This
$("<i />", {
  class: "fa fa-pencil-square text-warning",
  style: "margin-left: 0.5em; cursor: pointer;"
}).attr("data-toggle", "modal").attr("data-target", "#frmInsertPolicy").attr("aria-hidden", true).appendTo("#tabCustomers div:last h3:last");

// OR this
$("<i />", {
  class: "fa fa-pencil-square text-warning",
  style: "margin-left: 0.5em; cursor: pointer;"
}).attr("aria-hidden", true).appendTo("#tabCustomers div:last h3:last");
$("#tabCustomers div:last h3:last i:last").attr("data-toggle", "modal").attr("data-target", "#frmInsertPolicy");

// OR this
$("<i />", {
  class: "fa fa-pencil-square text-warning",
  style: "margin-left: 0.5em; cursor: pointer;"
}).data("toggle", "modal").data("target", "#frmInsertPolicy").attr("aria-hidden", true).appendTo("#tabCustomers div:last h3:last");

// OR this
$("<i />", {
  class: "fa fa-pencil-square text-warning",
  style: "margin-left: 0.5em; cursor: pointer;"
}).attr("aria-hidden", true).appendTo("#tabCustomers div:last h3:last");
$("#tabCustomers div:last h3:last i:last").data("toggle", "modal").data("target", "#frmInsertPolicy");
```

I debug the code and I confirm that the `<i>` DOM element is being created and the aria-hidden attribute is also being set, but for whatever reason the two data attributes are not being set.

**Update**
For those of you who have not bothered read the code that I tried and just want to mark the answer as a duplicate... I attempted to use the attr attribute both when the dynamic DOM element is being created and after the dynamic DOM element has been created.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.attr("data-toggle")` to persist the data attribute on the html DOM element. (`.data()` stores its values in jQuery.cache internally)

You can find more informations there :

http://api.jquery.com/data/

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is
>   accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values
>   are then stored internally in jQuery)

Comment: Provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing your issue it ll be simpler to help you